# intersection of nontrivial subgroup of R

Tags: group-theory

suppose R is a set of real numbers which is group under addition. let H and K are two non trivial subgroups of R then we want to know that whether intersection of H and K is trivial or not.
 i am stuck in finding example of two non trivial subgroups of R whose intersection is trivial or proving it can not be trivial.

Comment: Take $\;R=\Bbb Z/(6)=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}\pmod 6\;$ , and take $\;H=\{0,3\}\pmod 6\;,\;\;K=\{0,2,4\}\pmod 6\;$ ,  then $\;H\cap K=\{0\}\;$

Comment: sorry R is a set of real numbers

Comment: Yes, that was an important piece of information missing...:) But then you mean $\;\Bbb R\;$ , THE additive group of all real numbers, right?

Comment: Take $H = 2\Bbb Z$ and $K = 3\Bbb Z$, which are non-trivial subgroups of $(\Bbb R,+)$.

Comment: @David Wheeler $2\mathbb{Z}\cap 3\mathbb{Z}=6\mathbb{Z}\neq \{0\}$. Why not $2\mathbb{Z}\cap \sqrt{2}\mathbb{Z}=\{0\}$?

Comment: i want example of subgroups whose intersection is trivial or proving it is always non trivial

Answer (score 3):

We know $\sqrt{2}\notin \mathbb{Q}$. So we have $2\mathbb{Z}\cap \sqrt{2}\mathbb{Z}=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$Subgroups of $\R$ are either dense or discrete, that is, of the form $\alpha \Z$ for some $\alpha$.

If $H = \alpha \Z$ and $K = \beta \Z$ are both discrete (with $\alpha, \beta \ne 0$), then they intersect trivially iff $\alpha \beta^{-1} \notin \Q$.

If $H = \alpha \Z$, with $\alpha \ne 0$, and $K$ is dense, then there are examples in which the intersection is trivial, for instance when $K = \Q$, and $\alpha \notin \Q$.

If both $H$ and $K$ are dense, again there are examples with trivial intersection, for instance when $K = \Q$ and $H = \alpha \Q$, with $\alpha \notin \Q$.